# How to clean up user's SVN dir after server permissions change

Tags: permissions, svn, visualsvn

Our users had a full SVN checkout on their machines. We migrated the server to VisualSVN, and set up some permissions so that some subfolders are restricted. So now users who have no access still have the older version of those directories, and cannot delete nor update them.

Is there a way to clean it up without a full re-checkout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Fresh checkout will solve most (or all) troubles